# How to add file_fingerprint_lines option as a --log-opt option in docker run command for Docker AWS log driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, coreos, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm running my docker containers on CoreOS AWS instances and enabled aws log driver for the docker containers. Given below is my docker container run command.

```
docker run  --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=ap-southeast-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=stagingUrlMapperLogs --log-opt awslogs-datetime-format='\[%%b %%d, %%Y %%H:%%M:%%S\]' --log-opt tag="{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}" --net=host --name url-mapper url-mapper-example:latest
```

The issue is after some random period of time (1-2 days) on AWS CloudWatch side, no new log events are being recorded. After doing some research I came across [this issue reported on AWS developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268038&tstart=0). It says that adding **file_fingerprint_lines** option on CloudWatch config will solve the issue. But I didn't find any resources exaplaining **how to set the file_fingerprint_lines command with docker run command.**

**Note - I'm running my servers in AWS autosacaling group which is connected to a launch configuration, so each time I scale up, new servers will spin up with the container running on it.**

Answer (score 1):

"But I didn't find any resources exaplaining how to set the file_fingerprint_lines command with docker run command."

I think that you have to set it in the CloudWatch Logs agent configuration file:

From the [Amazon CloudWatch docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html):

> **file_fingerprint_lines**
>
> Specifies the range of lines for identifying a file. The valid values
>   are one number or two dash delimited numbers, such as '1', '2-5'. The
>   default value is '1' so the first line is used to calculate
>   fingerprint. Fingerprint lines are not sent to CloudWatch Logs unless
>   all the specified lines are available

But, I think that the interesting point comes here:

> **What kinds of file rotations are supported?**
>
> The following file rotation mechanisms are supported:
>
> Renaming existing log files with a numerical suffix, then re-creating
>   the original empty log file. For example, /var/log/syslog.log is
>   renamed /var/log/syslog.log.1. If /var/log/syslog.log.1 already exists
>   from a previous rotation, it is renamed /var/log/syslog.log.2.
>
> Truncating the original log file in place after creating a copy. For
>   example, /var/log/syslog.log is copied to /var/log/syslog.log.1 and
>   /var/log/syslog.log is truncated. There might be data loss for this
>   case, so be careful about using this file rotation mechanism.
>
> Creating a new file with a common pattern as the old one. For example,
>   /var/log/syslog.log.2014-01-01 remains and
>   /var/log/syslog.log.2014-01-02 is created.
>
> The fingerprint (source ID) of the file is calculated by hashing the
>   log stream key and the first line of file content. To override this
>   behavior, the **file_fingerprint_lines** option can be used. When file
>   rotation happens, the new file is supposed to have new content and the
>   old file is not supposed to have content appended; the agent pushes
>   the new file after it finishes reading the old file.

And, how to override it:

> You can have more than one [logstream] section, but each must have a
>   unique name within the configuration file, e.g., [logstream1],
>   [logstream2], and so on. The [logstream] value along with the first
>   line of data in the log file, define the log file's identity.

```
[general]
state_file = value
logging_config_file = value
use_gzip_http_content_encoding = [true | false]

[logstream1]
log_group_name = value
log_stream_name = value
datetime_format = value
time_zone = [LOCAL|UTC]
file = value
file_fingerprint_lines = integer | integer-integer
multi_line_start_pattern = regex | {datetime_format}
initial_position = [start_of_file | end_of_file]
encoding = [ascii|utf_8|..]
buffer_duration = integer
batch_count = integer
batch_size = integer

[logstream2]
...
```

Comment: I'm running my servers in AWS autosacaling group which is connected to a launch configuration, so each time I scale up, new servers will spin up with the container running on it. Is there any way to put this config to automatically available to all the  newly created servers automatically within the AutoScaleGroup

Comment: May [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html#enable-as-instance-metrics) helps you?

Comment: @juanium Thanks for the resources, but is there a way to achieve this on the docker run command itself as we do for other CloudWatch options?. (Refer my docker run command)

Comment: @RavinduFernando as I mentioned in the answer I think that you should set it in the CloudWatch Logs agent configuration file. As a guess I'll try adding the parameter as a `--log-opt` but I'm not sure if it will work, something like: `--log-opt  file_fingerprint_lines=...`